# How we can access VisualStateGroup of a Control

Tags: wpf, controls, visualstatemanager

I saw this [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278066(v=vs.110).aspx#DataGrid%20Parts). And I started wondering how I can access `VisualStateGroup` of a `DataGrid`, or of a `Button` from code ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [GetVisualStateGroups](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.visualstatemanager.getvisualstategroups(v=vs.110).aspx) method of `VisualStateManager`.

If `button` is the name of your control:

```
IList list = VisualStateManager.GetVisualStateGroups(button);
if (list.Count > 0)
{
    VisualStateGroup visualStateGroup = (VisualStateGroup)list[0];
    foreach (VisualState visualState in visualStateGroup.States)
    {
        // put here your logic
    }
}
```

Indeed `list` is an `ObservableCollection`, while `States` is a `FreezableCollection`. I hope it can help you.

Comment: I was trying to access default `VisualState` present in `Button`, but can't.

Comment: @AnjumSKhan, do you mean a `VisualState` for a specific control - with its own name - or in a style for a specific type of control?

Comment: Any default control which we use it can be a normal Button / CheckBox / DataGrid.

Comment: I am sorry @AnjumSKhan, I can't see the point. What is your target?

Comment: Drag a `Button` control on your `Window` , and now how to access its `VisualStates` in code-behind ?